# STORE DATA APDU for PPSE info

Tags: smartcard, apdu, microchip

I have installed PPSE on card, and now I have to add some data to get right response to SELECT command, but can't understand how to do it.

I guesss, I shoul use STORE DATA with FCI template.
My APDU:
`84E28000359102.....`
This is the only STORE DATA command, but also I tried APDU which starts like this:
`84E20000....`
For both APDU I got responses 6A86 - Incorrect P1 or P2 parameter. But there are no another options for these parameters, and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Have you tried P1= 88? (first '8' because it is the only block, so it is the last one, and second '8' because the payload is a DGI structure - the application might be expecting it)